# Adding generic type objects

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have an array list of generic types and i'm trying to create a method to calculate the average, but I cannot add the a generic without casting it first but I'm suppose to pass in integers or double how can i do this?

```
private ArrayList<T> grades;

public double computeAverage()
{
    double average = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++) {
        sum = sum + grades.get(i);  <<< ERROR
    }

    average = sum/grades.size();

    return average;

}
```

Error: The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) double, 
 T

Comment: What's your error?  Also, show how you define `grades`.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you showed us your error.  Now, is `T` declared at the class level?  How do you instantiate the instance of this object?

Comment: @Makoto I guess that information doesn't really matter here. Clearly we can't use `+` operator with type `T`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Still, after your edit, its unclear what `T` is. If you're able to narrow it down to a `Number` (which is the super class for `Integer` and `Double` as you mentioned), the following will work:

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();

for (Number number : numbers) {
    sum += number.doubleValue();
}
```